# Lazarus/Pascal: how do I show web content within a form

Tags: html, forms, browser, webforms, lazarus

I'm planning on building an application that simplifies web design. I intent using Lazarus/FreePascal for this.

My question is, how do I show HTML content on a Lazarus form as it would appear on the Browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FPC is cross-platform you will not know in advance what webbrowser a user will have installed so you cannot simply embed a TWebBroser.

There are some controls available that embed a specific engine like Gecko or Webkit. Read all about it on the wiki: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Webbrowser and especially in the last part of that page.

Comment: Good point - I forgot the cross-platform issues... I think I'll try out TurboPower, the standard Pascal library. Thanks!